# Search result auto complete does not display iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I've tried reading the google places API. and tried to duplicate their work. But I think I'm missing some steps here.

Here is the code for header my header file.

```
@class SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery;

@interface GoogleMapViewViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate>
{
    NSArray *searchResultPlaces;
    SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery *searchQuery;
    MKPointAnnotation *selectedPlaceAnnotation;

    BOOL shouldBeginEditing;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

My implementation file

```
#import "GoogleMapViewViewController.h"
#import "SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery.h"
#import "SPGooglePlacesAutocompletePlace.h"


@interface GoogleMapViewViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end

@implementation GoogleMapViewViewController
@synthesize mapView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        searchQuery = [[SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery alloc] init];
        searchQuery.radius = 100.0;
        shouldBeginEditing = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search or Address";
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setMapView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [searchResultPlaces count];
}

- (SPGooglePlacesAutocompletePlace *)placeAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [searchResultPlaces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:16.0];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self placeAtIndexPath:indexPath].name;
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate

- (void)recenterMapToPlacemark:(CLPlacemark *)placemark {
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;

    span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;

    region.span = span;
    region.center = placemark.location.coordinate;

    [self.mapView setRegion:region];
}

- (void)addPlacemarkAnnotationToMap:(CLPlacemark *)placemark addressString:(NSString *)address {
    [self.mapView removeAnnotation:selectedPlaceAnnotation];

    selectedPlaceAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    selectedPlaceAnnotation.coordinate = placemark.location.coordinate;
    selectedPlaceAnnotation.title = address;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:selectedPlaceAnnotation];
}

- (void)dismissSearchControllerWhileStayingActive {
    // Animate out the table view.
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.3;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SPGooglePlacesAutocompletePlace *place = [self placeAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [place resolveToPlacemark:^(CLPlacemark *placemark, NSString *addressString, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            SPPresentAlertViewWithErrorAndTitle(error, @"Could not map selected Place");
        } else if (placemark) {
            [self addPlacemarkAnnotationToMap:placemark addressString:addressString];
            [self recenterMapToPlacemark:placemark];
            [self dismissSearchControllerWhileStayingActive];
            [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
        }
    }];
}

#pragma mark UISearchDisplayDelegate

- (void)handleSearchForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    searchQuery.location = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    searchQuery.input = searchString;
    [searchQuery fetchPlaces:^(NSArray *places, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            SPPresentAlertViewWithErrorAndTitle(error, @"Could not fetch Places");
        } else {
            searchResultPlaces = places;
            [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
        }
    }];
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self handleSearchForSearchString:searchString];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)searchController:(UISearchController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self handleSearchForSearchString:searchString];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}



#pragma mark UISearchBar Delegate

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if (![searchBar isFirstResponder]) {
        // User tapped the 'clear' button.
        shouldBeginEditing = NO;
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO];
        [self.mapView removeAnnotation:selectedPlaceAnnotation];
    }
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    if (shouldBeginEditing) {
        // Animate in the table view.
        NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.3;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.alpha = 1.0;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    }
    BOOL boolToReturn = shouldBeginEditing;
    shouldBeginEditing = YES;
    return boolToReturn;
}

#pragma mark MKMapView Delegate

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViewIn viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if (mapViewIn != self.mapView || [annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    static NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteAnnotation";
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
    if (!annotationView) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
    }
    annotationView.animatesDrop = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [detailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(annotationDetailButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = detailButton;

    return annotationView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
    // Whenever we've dropped a pin on the map, immediately select it to present its callout bubble.
    [self.mapView selectAnnotation:selectedPlaceAnnotation animated:YES];
}

- (void)annotationDetailButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    // Detail view controller application logic here.
}


@end
```

I am really confused now to my implementation file as I cannot really understand what is in there TBH.plus some codes here are mostly deprecated. Someone care to give a detailed guide about this? or explain to me in layman's term. TIA.

Comment: can you show your storyboard? I guess outlets are messed up and delegates are not set properly.

Comment: I can't send my screenshot directly, but I only have a searchbar, and a MKMapView in my xib file...

Comment: Attach a screenshot showing all the mappings. Are you using a UISearchDisplayController or the one that comes embedded with the UITableViewController? or just a plain UISearchBar??

Comment: Sorry I can't send attachment of the screenshot. Well My UI is simple.. inside the Xib file.. only has 1 mapview, and 1 plain UISearchBar..

Comment: Hi @satheeshwaran i just edited my xib file and used the UISearchbarAndSearchDisplayController now it enters the delegate. but now it says could not fetch places..

Comment: Add breakpoints at this place,     [searchQuery fetchPlaces:^(NSArray *places, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            SPPresentAlertViewWithErrorAndTitle(error, @"Could not fetch Places");
        } else {
            searchResultPlaces = places;
            [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
        }
    }];

Comment: check what is the error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWERED!

Basically my problem was in this function given on the sample project of google places API..

```
BOOL SPEnsureGoogleAPIKey() {
    BOOL userHasProvidedAPIKey = YES;
    if (![kGoogleAPIKey isEqualToString:@"AIzaSyA2vs9pJoLrLs6XU8IRVHo7WxiuMufYXl8"]) {
        userHasProvidedAPIKey = NO;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"API Key Needed" message:@"Please replace kGoogleAPIKey with your Google API key." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    return userHasProvidedAPIKey;
}
```

The if statement originally is incorrect that's why it always gives me the wrong value. now its working :)  just added the not "!" in if

Comment: Grrrr!!!! that error variable should have told you this is the problem, anyways you found the issue.